# How does local socket IPC work on a multi CPU system?

Tags: linux, ipc

There is the Supermicro X10DAi motherboard and the manual is [here](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C612/MNL-1563.pdf). On page 1-11 you can see that each CPU has it's own RAM.

Let's say `program A` is offering an API through a local socket `/var/run/socketapi`. This program is started on CPU 1.

Then there is `program B` connecting to this socket and it's started on CPU 2.

When `program B` writes a command to the socket the kernel normally copies the data from the memory space of `program B` to that of `program A`.

But because the programs run on different CPUs and the memory is not shared between CPUs there is a problem.

How is this solved under recent Linux? Maybe the whole memory of CPU 1 is memory mapped to CPU 2 using the QPI interface shown in the manual?

Or perhaps the program IPC won't work and an error occurs?

Please provide some reference to Linux source code or documentation.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access and also see what `lscpu` says about Sockets and NUMA nodes. If the CPUs didn't have access to each other's memory, the system would pretty much be two distinct computers...

Comment: @ilkkachu The CPUs have separate memory buses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CPUs map each other's memory through the CPU interconnect.

On Intel-compatible architectures, that is a [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) mapping, so software notices mostly in the form of higher latency when accessing memory connected to the other CPU.

As system memory has quite a bit of latency on its own, the difference is not that great. The OS still optimizes on the fly, and might decide to move two processes that have lots of IPC traffic onto the same node.

Different architectures might have non-coherent mappings as well, which requires software to be more explicit about memory locality, but scales better with more sockets.

Comment: Do I have to be aware of multiple CPUs as a programmer? (When writing a normal user space program, no kernel programming.)

Comment: @zomega, in a single-threaded program, no. In a multi-threaded program, there is little difference between multiple threads on the same core, multiple threads on different cores in the same socket, and multiple threads on different sockets -- all the synchronization primitives are supposed to work for either setup.